# Ant: Are jarfile and destfile the same?

Tags: ant, jar

In the Ant documentation on the [jar command](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html), it says that the destfile attribute is required.

However there is an example at the bottom that uses the jarfile attribute and does not use the destfile attribute. Also, I have functioning code from a work colleague that uses the jarfile attribute in a build.xml file for a Netbeans project.

So it would seem that destfile is not required, or can be replaced by jarfile.
Are jarfile and destfile identical?
Are there cases where you should use one and cases where you should use the other?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `jarfile` is a deprecated alias for `destfile`.

The implementation of `jar` is a subclass of the implementation of `zip` - as is `ear` and `war`.  Each of them has a special `(zip|jar|war|ear)file` attribute.  With Ant 1.5 we decided to unify this to `destfile` and deprecate the task-specific attributes.

Obviously we forgot to update all references inside the manual :-)